# jenkins password encryption, escaping ${} characters

Tags: encryption, jenkins, groovy, escaping, special-characters

I am trying to encrypt the string `${PASSWD}` using the following groovy script. using \ for escaping $ and \ for { or }

```
import hudson.util.Secret

def secret = Secret.fromString("\$\\{PASSWD\\}")
println(secret.getEncryptedValue())

def decrypt = Secret.fromString("/WaEf5KeDpbhnjW+hBmV3kmpmQbwoTFh2oI1yFSuUf0=")
println(decrypt.getPlainText())
```

I get the following output:

```
/WaEf5KeDpbhnjW+hBmV3kmpmQbwoTFh2oI1yFSuUf0=
/WaEf5KeDpbhnjW+hBmV3kmpmQbwoTFh2oI1yFSuUf0=
```

However, the desired output should have been

```
/WaEf5KeDpbhnjW+hBmV3kmpmQbwoTFh2oI1yFSuUf0=
${PASSWD}
```

It seems that I am not using escape characters properly. How can I pass `${PASSWD}` as a string?

Answer (score 2):

Just use single quotes

```
def secret = Secret.fromString('${PASSWD}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you want to escape things, this is very useful:
https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4

For using the secret storage, I needed to use the 6 times backslash to get 1 backslash, which I eventually needed in a sed command to escape forward slashes.